# Поиск повторяющихся символов

Tags: php

```
$str = 'text text !!!!!!';
```

Как удалить `!!!!!!`?

P.s: Кол-во `!` может быть разное. Не удалять только если `!` один, в остальных случаях удалять все, не оставляя даже один `!`

Comment: регуляркой, найти `!{2,}` заменить на `!`

Comment: @Lexx918 слово "заменить" отсутствует в тексте публикации

Comment: @Елена: _"...в остальных случаях удалять все..."_ = replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$str = 'text text !!!!!!';
echo preg_replace('#!{2,}#us', '', $str); // text text

?>
```